# embedded linux commands with sed

Tags: bash

I am new to shell scripting. I am looking for a script which help me to achieve the below requirements:

1. I have java threaddump file and a script to analyze it. the analyzing script gives me around 15 lines of out put.
2. I have a template for html page.
3. I want to append the analyzing scripts output into line number 15 of the html page and the date and hostname into line number 4.

I tried a couple of options with the sed command but failing to insert the other linux commands inside the sed command.

```
#sed -i '15i 'hostname'' test.html
#sed -i '15i "`hostname`"' test.html
#sed -i '15i "hostname"' test.html
#sed -i '15i `hostname`' test.html   --> These options i tried but no luck.
```

Please help

Comment: What are you going to do with the html afterwards? Perhaps [Server Side Includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes) could obviate your current problem?

Comment: Or some other server-side scripting language. Either way, we probably need to see the HTML templates and an example of the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

You should use this from shell

```
sed -i "15i `hostname`" test.html
```

"" will evaluate text inside, `` will execute text as script and paste in its output